# Width of elements in flex container depends on content in last element

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have row-container which contains 3 row-cell with content. Third cell may be empty

```
   <div class="row-container">
    <div class="row-cell">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Some content 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-cell">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Some content 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-cell">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Some content 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Width of these elements depends on number elements.

If third cell not empty:

```
  .row-cell{
   &:nth-child(1){
    flex: 1;
  }

  &:nth-child(2){
    flex: 1;
  }

   &:nth-child(3){
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

If third cell is empty:

```
 .row-cell{
   &:nth-child(1){
    flex: 1;
  }

  &:nth-child(2){
    flex: 2;
  }
}
```

How should I write styles to make it work in same time?

Comment: You mean to say the style should be applied to first two rows and not the third row right ?

Comment: I mean if third cell is not empty, width for each element should be 33% (flex: 1).
If third element is empty, with for first cell should be 40% (flex:1),  and for second cell 60% (flex: 2)

Comment: check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Not possible with CSS AFAIK. You would need JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudoclass & `max-width` rule:

```
.row-cell {
  flex: 1;

  &:nth-child(1) {
    max-width: 40%;
  }

  &:nth-child(3):empty {
    max-width: 0;
  }
}
```

Transforming sass in css we can have a third child with content...

```css
.row-container{
  display: flex;
}

.row-cell{
  flex: 1;
}

.row-cell:nth-child(1){
  max-width: 40%;
}

.row-cell:nth-child(3):empty{
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#ff0000">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some content 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#00ff00">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some content 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#0000ff">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some content 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...or without any content:

```css
.row-container{
  display: flex;
}

.row-cell{
  flex: 1;
}

.row-cell:nth-child(1){
  max-width: 40%;
}

.row-cell:nth-child(3):empty{
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#ff0000">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some content 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#00ff00">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Some content 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-cell" style="background-color:#0000ff"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest an additional selector in your `nth-child(2)` rule, checking if it is also the last element. If it is, you increase the flex number.

```
.row-cell {
  &:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1;
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1;

    &:last-child {
        flex: 2;
    }
  }

  &:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked if the third element were missing, but in my case there is third element, but without any content.